# pdflatex hangs on centercolon plus tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, mathtools

When using centercolon inside a tikz picture, pdflatex hangs without any error message.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{{:}}{operators}{"3A} 
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node [label=above:{$:=$}]{} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know why that happens? Any ideas how to fix it?

My system: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/TeX Live for opensuse.org) on OpenSuSE 42.3.

Comment: Because `centercolon` makes `:` active, but it is also a part of the input format used in `tikz`. You get a similar problem with languages that makes `"` or `=` active.

Comment: Are you sure the `label=above:{$:=$}` is correct ? I would have used `above,label={$:=$}` instead ?

Comment: @BambOo it is an advertised interface in the TikZ manual, see for example at the top of page 52 in the manual, section 3.9 item 2.

Comment: @daleif, my bad !

Comment: I agree with @daleif. However, in the case of active characters in languages, one can fix the issue by loading `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, which just consists of the mysterious line `\tikzset{
  handle active characters in code,
  handle active characters in nodes
}`. Yet this does not fix the issue in this case. Most likely, one could fix it along the lines Ti*k*Z fixes the language thingy, but it is not clear to me that this will be worth the effort.

Comment: what is this ``\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{{:}}{operators}{"3A}``? this is very strange it does not raise an error. The second argument should be `\mathord` or whatever. I confirmed by looking at trace that the `\DeclareMathSymbol` works by sheer luck. It is same as using `\mathalpha`.

Comment: @marmot did you get that to work? I thought I tested that and it still hung

Comment: @daleif No, I didn't. Sorry, if my above comment is misleading. And I guess that jfbu is right in that this declaration is unfortunate regardless of Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable `centercolon` at the beginning of every `tikzpicture`, and then use `\vcentcolon` in place of `:` inside the nodes, or reactivate `centercolon` just for inside the nodes.

I followed the comment of @jfbu to define a style `centercolon` that deactivate/reactivate the `:`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{centercolon}

% disable 'centercolon' for every tikzpicture
\tikzset{
  centercolon/.code = {\csname MH_set_boolean_F:n\endcsname {center_colon}\mathtoolsset{centercolon=#1}},
  centercolon/.default=true,
  every picture/.prefix style = {centercolon=false},
  every node/.append style={centercolon},
  every node/.append style={scale=7, opacity=.5} % <-- just to compare the results
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)
      node [red, centercolon=false]{$:=$}
      node [blue]  {$:=$}
      node [green] {$\vcentcolon=$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**NOTES :**

- The blue and the green nodes are exactly the same, the red one is with `centercolon=false`
- The simple use of `\mathtoolsset{centercolon}` after `\mathtoolsset{centercolon=false}` do not restore the active `:` to be like `\vcentcolon`, as pointed by @jfbu in the comment below.

[image]

Comment: side note: trace of ``\mathtoolsset{centercolon}`` takes 1215 lines due to ``xkeyval`` which is loaded by ``standalone`` class, compared to 101 lines only with ``article`` class and then only ``keyval`` is used...  anyway it is a "feature" of ``mathtools`` that when you do ``\mathtoolsset{centercolon=false}`` then ``\mathtoolsset{centercolon=true}`` it does not reset the mathcode of ``:`` to ``32768`` thus it is not made math active. The explanation is that turning off does not reset the internal boolean ``center_colon`` to false. When turning on again, the boolean is true and mathcode not set

Comment: @jfbu so how should we "reactivate" the `:` after `\mathtoolsset{centercolon=false}` ? If you want you can edit my answer ...

Comment: problem is if I use ``font=\ERROR`` it does not raise any error. So I can't fix this in the style of your answer without your TikZpertise...

Comment: ``\def\foo{\csname MH_set_boolean_F:n\endcsname {center_colon}\mathtoolsset{centercolon=true}}`` and find a way to get `\foo` executed at start of node label and node contents. Works when I add manually ``\foo`` to both.

Comment: @jfbu the problem was my bad code: after setting `font=\foo` I erased this setting with the next `every node/.style = ...`, instead of using, as it should be, the `every node/.append style = ...`. Finally the code was modified using your comment, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

My two cents about how to debug tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mathtoolsset{centercolon}    

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@startup@env{%
  \lccode`~`;
  \lowercase{\let\tikz@activesemicolon~}%
  \lccode`~`:
  \lowercase{\let\tikz@activecolon~}%
  \lccode`~`|
  \lowercase{\let\tikz@activebar~}%
% (original coding is not good style in \ifnum tests)
  \ifnum\catcode`\;=\active\let\tikz@origsemi=\tikz@activesemicolon\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\:=\active\let\tikz@origcolon=\tikz@activecolon\fi
  \ifnum\catcode`\|=\active\let\tikz@origbar=\tikz@activebar\fi
% missing origexlmark ??
  \tikz@deactivatthings
  \iftikz@handle@active@code
    \tikz@switchoff@shorthands
  \fi
}

\begingroup
\catcode`;\active
\catcode`:\active
\catcode`|\active
\catcode`!\active
\gdef\tikz@deactivatthings{%
    \def;{\ifnum\catcode`;=\active\expandafter\tikz@nonactivesemicolon
          \else\expandafter\tikz@activesemicolon\fi}%
    \def:{\ifnum\catcode`:=\active\expandafter\tikz@nonactivecolon
          \else\expandafter\tikz@activecolon\fi}%
    \def|{\ifnum\catcode`|=\active\expandafter\tikz@nonactivebar
          \else\expandafter\tikz@activebar\fi}%
% does not seem to be handled in \tikz@startup@env
    \def!{\tikz@nonactiveexlmark}%
}
\endgroup

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node [label=above:{$:=$}]{} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I have tested only on this, so probably it breaks everything else...

[image]

Comment: the problem which might impact my code proposal is that Babel is buggy regarding math active characters. At least it was a few years back, Well it still is: it allows language definition files to use ``\string :`` as fall-back for example even in math mode. This is another way to end up in infinite loop when the character is math active. I think my package mathastext may contain a general way to fix this, at least that's what it wrote in its code comments, but offhand I have forgotten the details.

Comment: On reading more of tikz code, I see things such as ``\expandafter\pgfutil@ifnextchar\tikz@activebar``. This is probably broken by my code, but it should be ok without the ``\expandafter`` from brief look at what ``\pgfutil@ifnextchar`` does.